# How to visit different branches of a git server?

Tags: php, git, nginx

Some key word to my question

> Nginx wildcard domain name,
>   git

I don't know if this translation is right, in my native language it's 泛域名

Question: There are several GIT branches on Nginx server, I want to visit every single branch's code through typing the URL `xxx.example.com/` where `xxx` is the name of the branch's name.

I think maybe there should be several folders on my server and each folder is exactly one git branch, so I can visit every branch's code through the routing of Nginx configuration,

How should I create folders which can be visited for every branch's code?
How to refresh all the code when I push to the master branch?

I just know there are some relations between my question and GIT HOOKS
And I should configure Nginx server so different url can be directed to different folder on my server.

Maybe the structure of the server is like this:

> - master
>
>   - .git
>   - index.php
>   - others
> - AAA
>
>   - index.php
>   - others
> - BBB
>
>   - index.php
>   - others

AAA has the same code with the `AAA` branch of master.

BBB has the same code with the `BBB` branch of master

Comment: If you have SSH access to server.Then you can checkout one branch at a time and check it from same url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got some help from my friend and it works, actually my question can be simplified into two parts:

1.generating every git branches code

2.configure different paths for each branch's project.

And I'm gonna solve the first one.

[git branches example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ah3sl.png)

The first question just as I mentioned is about "git hooks", the train of thought is to checkout branches' code every time when "pull operation" occurs, a shell can automatically run by using git hooks, which locate in

```
.git/hooks/
```

There already exists some samples, we can start-up these shells by remove the extension .sample, for example post-receive file, this file runs after a git pull operation is done, here is the method that checkout every branches code:(is written into post-receive file, and please modify your path)

```
#!/bin/sh
#-------------- For Visiting branches --------------
#--The stucture of project
#--    -serverFolder
#--      -.git
#--        -hooks
#--        -info
#--        -branchProject
#--          -221
#--            -.git
#--            -application
#--            -system
#--            -others
#--          -222
#--            -.git
#--            -application
#--            -system
#--            -others
#--      -application
#--      -system
#--      -others
#--      
#--------------------------------------------

DST_DIR="branchPorject"
CLONE_PATH="your remote project path"

read oldrev newrev
ver=$(echo $newrev | cut -d "/" -f 3)
dst_path=$DST_DIR/${ver//\./""}

if [ ! -d $dst_path ];then
    mkdir -p $dst_path
    chmod -R 775 $DST_DIR
    chmod -R 775 $dst_path
    cd $dst_path
    env -i git clone $CLONE_PATH  #$dst_path
    env -i git config --add core.filemode false
fi

###################################################
# deploy
cd $dst_path

is_bare=$(git config --get --bool core.bare)
if [ "$is_bare" == "true" ];then
    echo "ERROR: only not bare repo can deploy"
    exit 1
fi

env -i git checkout $ver
env -i git pull
env -i chmod -R 775 $dst_path
```

now we have branch 221 and branch 222 's project in .git folder, the structure is showed in the shell behind. By configure the nginx or apache rewrite regulation, we can visit the different branches through the browser, maybe by typing URL like this to visit them:

```
http://example.221.com

http://example.222.com

http://example.master.com
```

I think this is convenient for web project test.